# Fastest most efficient way to determine decimal value is integer in Java

Tags: java, primitive

Given a double variable named `sizeValue` and `sizeValue` contains something other than 0, what is the most efficient way to determine that `sizeValue` contains a value that is an integer?

Currently i'm using

sizeValue % 1 == 0

any other faster ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

give a try to [Math.ceil](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html):

```
private static boolean isInt(double x) {
     return x == Math.ceil(x);
}
```

**EDIT**

I've done some benchmarks with the following methods:

```
private static boolean isInt1(double x) {
    return x == (int) x;
}

private static boolean isInt2(double x) {
    return x == Math.ceil(x);
}

private static boolean isInt3(double x) {
    return x % 1 == 0;
}
```

`isInt1` is the faster of them (on a sunjre 1.6)

Comment: Is Math.ceil faster?  - If so, why?  What magic is it doing? :-)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it is any faster, but you could cast your double to an int and test for equality:

```
double d = 123.456;
boolean dIsAnInteger = (d == (int)d);
```

Comment: -1 Doesn't work beyond 2^31. Using long would only be slightly less wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: would you consider `0.9999999999999999` an integer? Probably not. But watch this:

```
double val = 0;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    System.out.println(val+=0.1);
```

This prints out:

```
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
```

Which is problematic because at the end of the program `val` contains something that you think should be integer but is not.

So I'd make my method a bit slower (but more correct) by integrating a delta like [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html) does:

```
private static boolean isInt(double x, double delta) {
    double ceil = Math.ceil(x);
    return x-delta<ceil && x+delta>ceil;
}
```

and of course provide the same method with a sensible default:

```
private static boolean isInt(double x) {
    return isInt(x, 0.000000001);
}
```

Now `isInt(val)` finally returns true.