# How to test if a double is an integer

Tags: java, math

Is it possible to do this?

```
double variable;
variable = 5;
/* the below should return true, since 5 is an int. 
if variable were to equal 5.7, then it would return false. */
if(variable == int) {
    //do stuff
}
```

I know the code probably doesn't go anything like that, but how *does* it go?

Comment: C# but similar in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4077262/284240 ([Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE))

Comment: What would you gain out of this?  `double` and `int` are represented in memory differently, and you would use one or the other based on the context of your memory handling.

Comment: @Legend, i would have done the same as you suggested; do you by chance know how the %1 compares efficiency-wise to the Math.floor(variable) other users suggested?

Comment: @Makoto It's a program to find pygatorean triples. Square roots can sometimes be double, but at the same time they can also sometimes be intergers. You get what I mean?

Comment: @JXPheonix:  So values can either be a floating-point value or an integer value.  Makes sense.

Comment: Posted edited now with explanation.

Comment: @G.Bach they are close to the same.

Comment: @JXPheonix: I think you meant "pythagorean" :)

Comment: @G. Bach haha, i believe i did.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest most efficient way to determine decimal value is integer in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575052/fastest-most-efficient-way-to-determine-decimal-value-is-integer-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a number is a double or an int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297975/check-if-a-number-is-a-double-or-an-int)

Answer (score 166, accepted):

```
if ((variable == Math.floor(variable)) && !Double.isInfinite(variable)) {
    // integer type
}
```

This checks if the rounded-down value of the double is the same as the double.

Your variable could have an int or double value and `Math.floor(variable)` always has an int value, so if your variable is equal to `Math.floor(variable)` then it must have an int value.

This also doesn't work if the value of the variable is infinite or negative infinite hence adding 'as long as the variable isn't inifinite' to the condition.

Comment: "If the argument is NaN or an infinity or positive zero or negative zero, then the result is the same as the argument." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29

Comment: @TimSchmelter: good catch.  It's also worth noting that NaN is not equal anything (including itself) but +/-Inf is equal to itself - so there are two edge cases!

Comment: Both Skon and Fouad posted much better answers.

Comment: @JoelChristophel: I don't agree. This is a good way as it eliminates the risk of type overflow. The only thing I didn't like was the assertion that the variable was an `int` if the `if` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @Bathsheba (Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY % 1) == 0 and its negative counterpart both evaluate to false.

Comment: Actually you're winning me round, in Java at least, where % for negatives is clearly defined.

Comment: Modulo operator is very slow (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977834/why-is-modulus-operator-slow). So this answer is good, but Fouad answer is better because type casting is very fast.

Answer (score 289):

Or you could use the modulo operator:

`(d % 1) == 0`

Comment: I really love the simplicity of this solution. It's both easy to read and to implement.

Comment: Very intuitive solution

Comment: In terms of computation, is it faster than `Math.rint(d)`?

Comment: Yes this is nice, but note well this is a Java solution and is not well-defined for negative `d` in C and C++.

Comment: In Sonar, this produces an issue "Equality tests should not be made with floating point values."

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 don't allows do that

Comment: @Arkady Visual Studio 2015? For Java?

Comment: Not allowed in Intellij for `Kotlin`, compile time error with message *Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Double' and 'Int'*

Comment: @iCantC try `(d % 1) == 0f` or `(d % 1) == 0.0`

Comment: Would be wrong if `d = 10.0`, because it is double

Answer (score 102):

Guava: [`DoubleMath.isMathematicalInteger`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/math/DoubleMath.html#isMathematicalInteger(double)).  (Disclosure: I wrote it.)  Or, if you aren't already importing Guava, `x == Math.rint(x)` is the fastest way to do it; `rint` is measurably faster than `floor` or `ceil`.

Comment: Didn't know about Math.rint
You're correct. It is way faster than Math.floor

Comment: Is this somehow preferable to Eng.Fouad's casting example?

Comment: @JoelChristophel: Yes.  Not all doubles with integer values are in the range of int, or even long, so that test won't work on them.

Comment: Gotcha. Then (d %1) == 0 is still valid.

Answer (score 28):

```
public static boolean isInt(double d)
{
    return d == (int) d;
}
```

Comment: Only works for values  in the `int` range. Using `long` has the same problem, but with a  wider working range.

Answer (score 12):

Try this way,

```
public static boolean isInteger(double number){
    return Math.ceil(number) == Math.floor(number); 
}
```

for example:

```
Math.ceil(12.9) = 13; Math.floor(12.9) = 12;
```

hence **12.9** is **not** integer,  nevertheless

```
 Math.ceil(12.0) = 12; Math.floor(12.0) =12;
```

hence **12.0** is integer

Answer (score 6):

Here is a good solution:

```
if (variable == (int)variable) {
    //logic
}
```

Comment: why the `(bool)` cast?

Comment: @xdavidliu No need for that. We can ignore it.

Comment: This may cause problems in Kotlin. One way to fix that is casting back to double:   
  
```x == (double)(int)x```

Comment: It is NOT good! What if the value is larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
Double.isFinite (value) && Double.compare (value, StrictMath.rint (value)) == 0
```

This sticks to core Java and avoids an equality comparison between floating point values (`==`) which is consdered bad.  The `isFinite()` is necessary as `rint()` will pass-through infinity values.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version for `Integer` and `Double`:

```
    private static boolean isInteger(Double variable) {
    if (    variable.equals(Math.floor(variable)) && 
            !Double.isInfinite(variable)          &&
            !Double.isNaN(variable)               &&
            variable <= Integer.MAX_VALUE         &&
            variable >= Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To convert `Double` to `Integer`:

```
Integer intVariable = variable.intValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to SkonJeet's answer above, but the performance is better (at least in java):

```
Double zero = 0d;    
zero.longValue() == zero.doubleValue()
```

Answer (score 2):

My simple solution:

```
private boolean checkIfInt(double value){
 return value - Math.floor(value) == 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isInteger(double d) {
  // Note that Double.NaN is not equal to anything, even itself.
  return (d == Math.floor(d)) && !Double.isInfinite(d);
}
```

Comment: A more correct implementation would return false and you would have to write another method that takes int as argument and returns true. :D

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer the simple modulo operation solution in the accepted answer.
Unfortunately, SonarQube doesn't like equality tests with floating points without setting a round precision. So we have tried to find a more compliant solution. Here it is:

```
if (new BigDecimal(decimalValue).remainder(new BigDecimal(1)).equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)) {
    // no decimal places
} else {
    // decimal places
}
```

`Remainder(BigDecimal)` returns a `BigDecimal` whose value is `(this % divisor)`. If this one's equal to zero, we know there is no floating point.

Answer (score 1):

Because of `%` operator cannot apply to BigDecimal and int (i.e. 1) directly, so I am using the following snippet to check if the BigDecimal is an integer:

```
value.stripTrailingZeros().scale() <= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way for doing this could be

```
    double d = 7.88;    //sample example
    int x=floor(d);     //floor of number
    int y=ceil(d);      //ceil of number
    if(x==y)            //both floor and ceil will be same for integer number
        cout<<"integer number";
    else
        cout<<"double number";
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be

```
double variable=the number;
if(variable-(int)variable=0.0){
 // do stuff
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try in this way: get the integer value of the double, subtract this from the original double value, define a rounding range and tests if the absolute number of the new double value(without the integer part) is larger or smaller than your defined range. if it is smaller you can intend it it is an integer value. Example:

```
public final double testRange = 0.2;

public static boolean doubleIsInteger(double d){
    int i = (int)d;
    double abs = Math.abs(d-i);
    return abs <= testRange;
}
```

If you assign to d the value 33.15 the method return true. To have better results you can assign lower values to testRange (as 0.0002) at your discretion.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution:

```
float var = Your_Value;
if ((var - Math.floor(var)) == 0.0f)
{
    // var is an integer, so do stuff
}
```