# How to determine whether a double variable has integer value?

Tags: java, math, integer, double, double-precision

I'm trying to find possible integer roots of a quadratic equation with Java.

[image]

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
double sqrtDiscriminant = Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c);

double  root1 = ((-1.0 * b) - sqrtDiscriminant) / (2.0 * a);
double  root2 = ((-1.0 * b) + sqrtDiscriminant) / (2.0 * a);
```

For `a = 2`, `b = -1` and `c = -40755`, one of the roots is `143.0`
(`143.0` is printed to console when I echo it so I'm only interested in such
double values, not `143.00001`)
My question is, how can I make sure that any root has an integer value?
If `root1 = 143.0` then e.g. `root1 == 143` should return true.

I tried `root1 == Math.floor(root1)` but it didn't work.

Comment: maybe root1*1000==Math.floor(root1) * 1000 ?

Comment: I think it would be better to check that `Double.intValue(root1)` when passed to the equation really satisfies it.

Comment: You'll never solve this at the numerical level. A finite computing machine is unable to model the full complexity of real numbers.

Comment: See [How to test if a double is an integer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898512/how-to-test-if-a-double-is-an-integer

Comment: You should make clear whether `a, b, c` are actually of some integer data type. If they are, exact verification is possible, otherwise you are in the domain of numeric imprecision and have to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I would be you, I will simply take the `int/long` value of the roots and re-verify the equation to make sure that `int/long` value of the root is OK or not e.g.

```
// using round because an equivalent int/long may be represented by a near binary fraction
// as floating point calculations aren't exact
// e.g. 3.999999.. for 4
long longRoot = Math.round(root1); 
if(a*longRoot*longRoot +  b*longRoot + c==0){
    //its valid int root
}else{
    //ignore it
}
```

Comment: hi yogendra, thanks for the tip. actually using _int_ wouldn't work for some cases in my problem (e.g. large valued roots), but using _long_ definitely helped.

Answer (score 3):

You should never use equality checks when working with double-values. Define an accuracy value like

```
double epsilon = 0.0000001;
```

Then check whether the difference is nearly equal to `epsilon`:

```
if(Math.abs(Math.floor(value)-value) <= epsilon) { }
```

Comment: You should use round as the rounding error might be slightly less tha the number desired.

Comment: This tests the wrong thing, it tests whether or not the supposed root is close to an integer; what is needed is a test to determine whether the closest integer to the supposed root is a root of the original equation.

Comment: Basically you're right. But choosing enough accuracy will lead to the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can test the integer value if it's a solution also:

```
x = Math.floor(root1);
if(a*x*x+b*x+c == 0)
...
```

Comment: This answer deals with the ambiguity between two cases: an equation with a root that is almost exactly an integer, and an equation with an integer root that is only approximated by the original solution. However, I think it would be better to use Math.rint to deal with the case of an approximation to an integer solution that is slightly less than the solution.

Comment: You can't have `²` in an identifier name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an integer result use round as your error might mean the number is slightly too large or slightly too small.

```
long l = Math.round(value);
```

To round to a fixed number of decimal places you can use

```
double d = Math.round(value * 1e6) / 1e6; // six decimal places.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as

```
Math.rint(d) == d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((variable == Math.floor(variable)) && !Double.isInfinite(variable)) {
    // int
}
```

If variable is equal to the Math.floor then its Integer. The infinite check is because its will not work for it.

Answer (score 0):

the best way will be check whether `(Math.floor(root1)-root1)<=0.0000001`
It will give you the correct output.