# Netbeans throwing a NumberFormatException

Tags: java, numberformatexception

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
>       at newform.fivth.(fivth.java:150)
>       at newform.fivth$3.run(fivth.java:623)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

This is the part of the code the error refers to:

```
while (results4.next())
{
for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
            {
         x.add(Integer.parseInt(results4.getString(i))+0.5);       

            }  

}
}
catch(SQLException sqlEx){
System.out.println(
"* Error retrieving data! *");
sqlEx.printStackTrace();
System.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Java, the string `"1.0"` cannot be represented as an `int`, but it can be represented a `double`.  The parsing logic for `Integer.parseInt` expects there *not* to be a decimal point, even if there is just a zero after the decimal point.

To quote the [Javadoc for `Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters
>   in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first
>   character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a
>   negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a
>   positive value.

It doesn't expect a decimal point.

If you must accept a `String` such as `"1.0"` and store the resulting `int`, then I would parse it as `Double` then call `intValue`.  Instead of the following:

```
Integer.parseInt(results4.getString(i))
```

I would use this:

```
Double.valueOf(results4.getString(i)).intValue()
```

Of course, you'll have to make the value really is an integer.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898512/how-to-test-if-a-double-is-an-integer) for those details.