# Represent double as integer without regex

Tags: java, double

I am developing a calculator for `android`. 
Having a `double` field called `result`, which I then put into a `TextView`.

If say `result = 20.0` then I must represent it as `20` (without point and a zero). If `result = 20.0001` it should be displayed unchanged.

Now I do it with regular expressions but I guess it's not a good idea. 
Is there another way to represent double without a point and a zero if double actually is an integer (without digits after the point)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `(d % 1 == 0) {` *to check if your double does not have a decimal part*, then use the `intValue()` method to get the `integer` out of the `Double`!

```
class testDouble {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double result = 20.001;
if (result % 1 == 0) {
    System.out.println(result + " Can be turned into integer, has no decimal part");
}
else {
    System.out.println(result + " Can not be turned into integer, has decimal part");
}
    result = 20.000;
if (result % 1 == 0) {
    System.out.println(result + " Can be turned into integer, has no decimal part");
    int intOfDouble = result.intValue();
    System.out.println(result + " Can be turned into integer " + intOfDouble);
}
}
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
20.001 Can not be turned into integer, has decimal part
20.0 Can be turned into integer, has no decimal part
20.0 Can be turned into integer 20
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick and exect answer

Comment: Glad that I could help and that it works! Please accept my answer as described here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ! Thanks !

Comment: Objection, your honor! OP said he has a `double` `result` not a `Double.` See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29109020/1744774) for a one-liner;

Answer (score 1):

I hope I could understand your question. Maybe this will help you to solve your problem.

```
    double d = 20.0001;
    if ((int) d == d)
        System.out.println((int) d);
    else
        System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about Explicit type casting

```
double y=anyValue;
int x = (int) y;
if(x==y)
log.debug(x);
else
log.debug(y);
```

for Input `y=3.00` the output will be `3`
and for Input `y=3.0001` the output will be `3.0001`

Answer (score 0):

You could output the result as a formatted string:

```
public static String fmt(double d)
{
    if(d == (long) d)
        return String.format("%d",(long)d);
    else
        return String.format("%s",d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus `%` operator.
Let us say your calculated value is:

```
double result;

if (x % 1) == 0   
    then you must have a whole number
    and you can use (int) result to cast it and int value
else //your number is not a whole number
    you will just use the result as is
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `double` `result` against a cast `(long) result` and create a string to be displayed accordingly with a one-liner:

```
double r;
String s;
for (int i = 2; i <= 3; i++) {
    r = 100d / i;
    // this is the essential line, all others are just testing noise
    s = r > (long) r ? String.valueOf(r) : String.valueOf((long) r);
    // ------------------------------------------------------------- 
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Prints:

```
50
33.333333333333336
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use modulus division like:

```
if((**doublevariablehere** % 1) == 0)
{
}
```

Code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9909417/4028085)