# Delphi check if double is an integer or not

Tags: delphi

I need to test if a double is an integer or not. Basically this is an example of the rule:

- 5.0 > true
- 5.2 > false

In order to do this I'd make an `if (result mod 1) = 0 then` and see the if it returns true or false. Consider that `result` is a double. By the way the compiler gives me this error:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(121): E2015 Operator not applicable to this
>   operand type

How can I solve this problem? Note that my numbers are in this format `##.#####` so I haven't many problems with the floating point precision.

In general I'd use `if (result % 1 == 0) {}` but in Delphi this does not work.

Comment: You can check if the fraction is close to zero. "math" has "IsZero" which you can provide an epsilon.

Comment: An exact integer, or close enough? If only an exact integer, keep in mind that simple things such as `0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2` don't necessarily evaluate to an exact integer. If close enough, how close?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz You could do that, but the same percentages in rounding errors that turn 1 into 1.0000001 turn 1000000 into 1000000.1. Only looking at the fractional part without taking the magnitude into account is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @hvd - You can provide different epsilons according to magnitude if it is differing too much.

Comment: Check this simple solution, hope it help someone :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449962/8545027

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the function `frac` declared in the System unit of Delphi. Try with this code:

```
if ( frac(result) = 0 ) then
 ShowMessage('is zero')
else
 ShowMessage('is NOT zero');
end;
```

Check the [documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Frac.html) for details about the function. What you are doing is wrong because in Delphi the keyword `mod` only works with Integers.

---

**Note**. I have tested this with numbers such as `45.1234` and the code is correct. I see that you have a little number of digits in your double so there shouldn't be problems. I am not sure how accurate that function is, but in this case you don't have to worry.

Comment: Be wary of using `Frac()` as _Delphi_ does have some issues with floats. Given a variable `V: Double` with the value **15.2**, `Frac(V)` returns **0.199999999999999**. This was using _Delphi 10.2_.

Answer (score 0):

That comparison would work in Freepascal....

```
{$mode objfpc}{$R+}
uses math;
var
  a:double =  5.2;
  b:double =  5.0;
begin
  writeln(a mod 1 = 0);
writeln(b mod 1 = 0);
end.
```

But it won't work in Delphi, I know...

In Delphi it should be with fmod:

```
uses math;
var
  a:double =  5.2;
  b:double =  5.0;
begin
  writeln(fmod(a,1) = 0);
  writeln(fmod(b,1) = 0);
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

A Variation on @Alberto's answer. Just refined slightly to allow one to choose how precise (or imprecise) you want to be:

```
// is the passed FP number effectively an "integer";
// i.e. when rounded to AToPlaces decimal places, does it have only zero after dec point?
// AToPlaces -ve => after the dec point; same convention as for RoundTo; range -20 .. +20
  
function IsInteger(AFloat: Extended; AToPlaces: TRoundToEXRangeExtended = -3): boolean;
begin
  // Careful, this didn't work until I switched the order of Frac and RoundTo
  result := RoundTo(frac(AFloat), AToPlaces) = 0;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe you want also to take care about the float imprecision, in this way you can do something like this :

```
if comparevalue(aValue, round(aValue), Tepsilon.vector) = 0 then 
  hasnodecimal 
else 
  hasdecimal
```

Comment: If you'd inspect source code of `comparevalue` you could simplify the code down to `Abs(aValue - Round(aValue)) < Tepsilon.vector` and then almost down to Alberto Miola answer of `frac(aValue) < Tepsilon.vector`.