# Kotlin: Check if a Double value is only between 0.0 to 1.0 stepped by 0.1

Tags: kotlin

What would be a simple/elegant solution to check if a double value is only in the set of
`{.0, .1, .. .9, 1.0}` 
values.

Right now I am doing

```
setOf(.0, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1.0)
```

and check if a Double value contains.

Is there a more simpler/elegant solution?

Comment: Multiply by 10 and see if that value is an integer?

Comment: How would you check if the result's decimals are all 0s?

Comment: @Dachstein https://stackoverflow.com/a/9898528

Comment: Honestly, unless the numbers change a lot, the set you have now seems simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it with [sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/index.html).

```
fun contains(d: Double) = d in generateSequence(0.0) { it + 0.1 }.takeWhile { it <= 1.0 }
```

If you want to make it shorter, add `step` function like there is one for `Int` sequences.

```
infix fun ClosedRange<Double>.step(step: Double): Sequence<Double> = 
    generateSequence(start) { it + step }.takeWhile { it <= endInclusive }

fun contains(d: Double) = d in 0.0..1.0 step 0.1
```

**Edit**

As mentioned in comment, simple `in` doesn't work because of complex `Double` calculations. Therefore you can add your own checking function:

```
val acceptableAccuracy = 1e-15
infix fun Double.nearlyIn(sequence: Sequence<Double>) = 
    sequence.any { this in (it - acceptableAccuracy..it + acceptableAccuracy) }
```

Then you need few changes in the code above:

```
fun contains(d: Double) = d nearlyIn (0.0..1.0 step 0.1)
```

Comment: unfortunately 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 is not 0.3 :(

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only really worried about the tens position, I'd just shift it once and check for 0..10:

```
fun Double.isSpecial() = (this * 10.0) in (0..10).map(Int::toDouble)
```

Testing with play.kotlinlang.org:

```
fun main() {
  listOf(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0).forEach(::checkSpecial)
  listOf(0.01, 0.11, 0.22, 1.01).forEach(::checkSpecial)
}

fun checkSpecial(value: Double) {
  println("$value isSpecial = ${value.isSpecial()}")
}
```

Outputs:

```
0.0 isSpecial = true
0.1 isSpecial = true
0.2 isSpecial = true
0.3 isSpecial = true
0.4 isSpecial = true
0.5 isSpecial = true
0.6 isSpecial = true
0.7 isSpecial = true
0.8 isSpecial = true
0.9 isSpecial = true
1.0 isSpecial = true
0.01 isSpecial = false
0.11 isSpecial = false
0.22 isSpecial = false
1.01 isSpecial = false
```

If you're less worried about elegance and more about performance, you could just do:

```
fun Double.isSpecial() = when (this) {
    0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0 -> true
    else -> false
}
```

Which avoids allocating any sets or ranges entirely. If the range isn't dynamic, I'd just go with this, personally.

Comment: Interesting solutions. Thanks

Comment: Although this is a "correct" solution according to the OP's stated requirements, it leaves me feeling uncomfortable because it compares double values for equality. This is not comparing that a value is, say, exactly 0.3; it's in fact comparing that a value is exactly equal to the IEEE binary representation that the compiler creates when it encounters the literal value "0.3" in source code. They're two different things. I'd much rather compare with a given tolerance.

Comment: That's a fair point. Guess it depends on how the values are being generated but comparing with a given tolerance would definitely be safer.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it if you want to check steps of 0.1 for any double.
Multiply by 10, check if the result is an integer.

```
fun isSpecial(v:Double) : Boolean {
    val y = v*10
    return y == y.toInt().toDouble()
}
```

Unless you explicitly only want 0.0-1.0 ?