# Cast double to int, but only if exact conversion

Tags: java

I'm getting a value of type `double` from an API which, in my specific case, should always return a whole number in a range well within `int`'s — any non-whole number will mean something went very wrong inside that API call. I do want to know when this happens.

I know I can do a post-conversion check like, let say:

```
double value = …;
int whole_number = (int) value;
if(value != whole_number) throw …;
```

Is there any shorter idiom to "Convert a `double` to `int` only if it is an exact conversion, and raise an exception if not"?

Comment: This question reminds me **strongly** of one I answered in...2008? May have to go looking...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder feel free to make it a duplicate, then. I couldn't find anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9909417/3182664 (ignore the accepted answer there)

Comment: @Marco13 Still not exactly an answer to his

Comment: @liori - It's such a vague memory... It was probably something else. :-)

Comment: @YassinHajaj I don't want to argue. Feel free to add a reopen vote. But if the point of the question is whether you can or have to wrap 3 lines of code into a `doMyStuff` utility method, then this should be pointed out more clearly. There's certainly no built-in functionality for that in the standard API.

Comment: @Marco13, I thought I made it clear with asking for "any shorter idiom".

Comment: The answer to this question is No.  There isn't a shorter idiom ... apart from the obvious one of "make it a method and call it".   I agree that this is a dup.

Comment: @liori You can check my answer in which I have used `intExactValue()` provided in `BigDecimal` class. It's a short and concise solution.

Comment: @StephenC You're right. If we see the implementation of `intExactValue()` method, it's not that much short. And I think we should use their implementation rather than writing the logic to check these conditions ourselves.

Comment: Yes ... but 1) it involves a **major** overhead of converting the `double` to a `BigDecimal`, and 2) it is not clear that it will give the same answer in all cases because of the difference between base 2 and base 10 representations.

Comment: @StephenC, if this is a dup, then how come none of the answers there answer my question? If the answer to my question is "no", then how about just writing an answer of "No" as an actual answer here?

Comment: Please read [The "reasonable user" theory of duplicate questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384711/the-reasonable-user-theory-of-duplicate-questions/384792#384792).  It applies to this case ... in my opinion.

Comment: @StephenC it would be if the decomposition was the answer. Not if the question is about *avoiding* decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems simplest to me. You can do it as a one-liner:

```
if (value != (int)value)) throw ...
```

but if you want the exception to be thrown *for* you, the only thing I can think of is to go through a String, which seems *really* convoluted, especially since you can't just use `String.valueOf(value)` to get the string:

```
// Seems really convoluted
Integer.parseInt(new DecimalFormat("##.###").format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following check if needed

```
if (value % 1 != 0) {
    throw...
}
```

Using an `Optional<Double>` you could use the following logic

```
Integer result = Optional.of(value)
                         .filter(d -> d % 1 == 0)
                         .filter(this::isInRange)
                         .map(Integer::parseInt)
                         .orElseThrow(...);
```

Comment: You aren't checking the `int` range here.

Comment: @ernest_k I didn't see it anywhere mentioned in the question explicitly but here it is :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BigDecimal::intValueExact()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValueExact()):

```
int wholeNumber = BigDecimal.valueOf(value).intValueExact();
```

It will automatically throw an exception: *if it has a **nonzero fractional part** or it is **outside the range of `int`***

Comment: So essentially what I wrote in my question, just with a different condition.

Comment: @liori now check the updated solution.