# What datatype should i use,if result coming in both decimal and non decimal

Tags: java, android

I am receiving points from database that is integer. After receiving points i am doing some calculation and showing result to user.
Assume i received 20, 21, ,22. I am doing 21/1.5+20+22 which results in 43.50, But some time the points i receives is all even so the result will be like 50.00.
The Problem Is i want to show 43.50 if decimal is not 00 And 50 If decimal is 00..
What data type should i use for calculation and show results like i mentioned above.THANKS.
Currently I am using this but using integer wont show the decimal

```
int tot = a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8+a9+a10+a11+a12+a13+a14+a15+a16+a17+a18+a19+a20+a21+a22+a23+a24;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the output in double datatype, and while showing put checks on it like this:

```
    Double result;
    if (result%1.0 == 0.0){
        // show result.intValue();
    } else {
        // show result System.out.printf("result : %.2f%n", result);
    }
```

Comment: While calculatiing should i use double?

Comment: @ZaidKhan yes, use Double while calculating otherwise data will be rounded off.

Comment: 1 More Question Which answer should i accept because every answer helps me out..

Comment: @ZaidKhan the one which helps you the most. And upvote all helping answers.

Comment: Can you explain me the condition in if statement?

Comment: @ZaidKhan check the EDIT. use %.2f%n to show 2 decimal places.

Comment: Dividing 50.00 with 1.0 results 50.0 how can this go true?

Comment: @ZaidKhan here % is modulus operator, not division. 50 is fully divided by 1.0 so mod is 0.0 and in case 50.25 it will give 0.25

Comment: https://www.edureka.co/blog/mod-method-in-java/ check this

Comment: Now i am clear i was dividing and got confused.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to present with exactly 2 decimal places you can use DecimalFormat e.g. and for calculating float point values you can use double or float type

```
DecimalFormat df   = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
String formatedTot = df.format(tot);
System.out.println(formatedTot);
```

Comment: I want to show 2 decimal places but if decimal places is not 00.

Answer (score 0):

From the description it's hard to point you in the correct direction.

Please show some code how you show the results in Android.

Regarding datatype it should be clear that you can't convert an `integer` to a `decimal` because you can't magically add decimal values to it. Therefore I guess you need a `decimal` datatype and need to check if it's an `integer` which is explained here: [How to test if a double is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9898512)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not in calculation, but in displaying the result. When you use `int` or `Integer` for your calculation, Java will always round down. Even `float` and `double` are only approximations ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)). Depending on how accurate you result should be use `float` (medium accuracy), `double` (ok accuracy) or `BigDecimal` (best accuracy).

To solve your issue, calculate your number as precise as required and define while printing how it should be represented as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `double` data type or `float` data type. If you need to check the remainder after the decimal point you could use something like,

```
            double num = 50.00;
            if (num % 1.0 == 0.0){
            int numOne = (int) num;
            System.out.println(numOne)
            }
```

The above [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63264163/7874617) (by Rajat Mehra) which I edited, will cast values with "0" remainder to an integer and display them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a set of integers.  Your question implies you do not want rounding so the result of your calculation should be a float or double.

```
double result = calculate(integers);
```

You note that you want to show the fractional portion of the calculated value even if the result is an integer.  Java has a variety of options to format the output.  One simple approach is using printf.

```
System.out.printf("result=%.2f%n", result);
```