# Method for converting float to integer after checking

Tags: java

I am trying to perform multiple operations on two numbers (say A and B). These two numbers are getting inputted via a single string. So I am converting them into `Double` values and performing an operation on them.

The poblem is that the output is always `double`. I would like to have the answer to be an integer answer if the result is an integer, say, `2` instead of `2.0`.

Cases:

1. `A= 2` and `B= 2` (input in string )=> extracted into float variables => varA= 2.0, varB=2.0 current result => 4.0 (simple * operation ) optimum result => `4`
2. `A= 2.0` and `B= 2.0` (input in string )=> extracted into float variables => varA= 2.0, varB=2.0 current result => 4.0 (simple * operation ) optimum result => `4.0`

I looked it up and it wasn't much help. As such questions either deal with conversion or precision. Links to any similar/helping questions that I might have missed will work too. I know how to convert from `float` to `int`, but looking for *optimum* way to check if a number can be represented in int or not. And get result accordingly.

Thank you

Comment: Even if the mathematical value is an integer, the result of a calculation with floating point numbers may not be (due to rounding errors).

Comment: @Henry yeah I read through those problems, I might change my code later. That's why I didn't focus on operator/operation part, just looking for conversion paths possible for me to take here.

Comment: The point is that converting a floating point value to an integer to make it look pretty is *mathematically unsound*.  You shouldn't do it.  And if "the boss" asks you to, you should explain the mathematics to him (or her) in order to convince him that the pretty answer is a wrong answer.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898512/how-to-test-if-a-double-is-an-integer

Comment: @StephenC that's so true haha.

Comment: @Abra thank you that works. little bit of wordings here and there (-_-). I swear it didn't 
 even pop up as suggestion when I was posting this question.

Comment: For your case two, you just cannot go through the Double data type because the decimal information will be lost. What about using a BigDecimal instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use % operator to decide if the two doubles produce a perfect division and use integer casting like below.

```
double num1 = 20.0;
double num2 = 5.0;
    
if (num1%num2 == 0) {
    System.out.println((long) (num1/num2));
} else {
    System.out.println(num1/num2);
}
```